# Strong Markov property on shifted Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, markov-process

This is a Corollary from Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion.

[image]

The proof below simply states that this is a corollary from the below equation (6.8) and the fact that $u(B_\tau)$ and $u(W_{\tau'} + B_\sigma)$ have the same distribution.

So we have $E[u(B_\tau) |\mathscr{F}_{\sigma+}](\omega) = E[u(W_{\tau'}+B_\sigma)|\mathscr{F}_{\sigma+}]$. And we need to show that this is equal to $E[u(W_{\tau'}+x)]|_{x=B_\sigma(\omega)}$ using (6.8).

However, $u$ here is a bounded measurable Borel function on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\Psi$ in (6.8) is a bounded $\mathscr{B}(\mathcal{C})/\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ measurable function. So I can't see how to define the $\Psi$ in (6.8) to get the first identity in (6.9).

How do we get the proof for this Corollary rigorously? I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]